# Kalman Filter - Updating the Covariance Matrix Step

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, kalman-filters, bayesian-estimation

I am trying to simulate the Kalman Filter. I have the covariance matrix `P_{0|0}`. Tell me please, how can I get the predicted (a priori) estimate covariance matrix on the (k-1) step? `P_{k-1|k-1}`?

Comment: Can you please share a little bit more information about what you are trying to do and more importantly what have you done so far, possibly including some code (?). That should be k+1 by the way, that is, the prediction step (in the future).

Comment: if you wish, I can send the code of Kalman filter to your e-mail and will be glad if you look at that. However, I need to understand only what the `P_{k-1|k-1}` means in that equation. How can I get that from the task conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the Covariance Matrix $ {P}_{k - 1 \mid k - 1} $ then:

$$ {P}_{k \mid k} = {F}_{k} {P}_{k - 1 \mid k - 1} {F}_{k}^{T} + {Q}_{k} $$

Where $ {F}_{k} $ is the Model Matrix at iteration $ k $ and $ {Q}_{k} $ is the Process Noise Covariance Matrix at iteration $ k $.

Comment: Probably, I describe the question unclearly. What is `P_{k-1|k-1}` means in that equation?

Comment: Are you after Smoothing using the Kalman Filter?